# Multithreading and sequence of instructions

Tags: c++, multithreading

While learning multithread programming I've written the following code.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

void check() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    {
        std::jthread t2([&](){
            int i = 0;
            while (a >= b) {
                ++i;
            }
            std::cout << "failed at iteration " << i << "\n"
                      // I know at this point a and b may have changed
                      << a << " >= " << b << "\n";
            std::exit(0);
        });
        std::jthread t1([&](){
            while (true) {
                ++a;
                ++b;
            }
        });
    }
}

int main() {
    check();
}
```

Since `++a` always happens before `++b` a should be always greater or equal to b.
But experiment shows that sometimes `b > a`. Why? What causes it? And how can I enforce it?

Even when I replace `int a = 0;` with `int a = 1000;` which makes all of this even more crazy.

The program exits soon so no int overflow happens.
I found no instructions reordering in assembly which might have caused this.

Comment: The above code has no synchronisation so there is a race-condition and we have Undefined Behaviour.  Once the UB is fixed we can try and reason about the threads. See __Threads and data races__ here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model  _"...If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined...."_

Comment: You are assuming that the `t2` thread reads both variables simultaneously.  `t2` can read `a` into a register then be unscheduled and `t1` can execute 100 iterations of the loop before `t2` is scheduled again it then reads `b` into a register thus making `b` much larger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Since ++a always happens before ++b a should be always greater or
> equal to b

***Only in its execution thread***. And only if that's ***observable*** by the execution thread.

C++ requires certain explicit "synchronization" in order for changes made by one execution thread be visible by other execution threads.

```
     ++a;
     ++b;
```

With these statements alone, there are no means by which this execution thread would actually be able to "tell the difference" whether `a` or `b` was incremented first. As such, C++ allows the compiler to implement whatever optimizations or code reordering steps it wants, as long as it has ***no observable effects*** in its execution thread, and if the actual generated code incremented `b` first there will not be any observable effects. There's no way that this execution thread could possibly tell the difference.

But if there was some intervening statement that "looked" at `a`, then this wouldn't hold true any more, and the compiler would be required to actually generate code that increments `a` before using it in some way.

And that's just this execution thread, alone. Even if it was possible to observe the relative order of changes to `a` in `b` in this execution thread the C++ compiler is allowed, by the standard, to actually increment the actual variables in any order, as long as there are also any other adjustments that make this not observable. But it could be observable by another execution thread. To prevent that it will be necessary to take explicit ***synchronization*** steps, using mutexes, condition variables, and other parts of C++'s execution thread model.

Answer (score 0):

There are non-trivial race conditions between the increment of these different variables and when you read them. If you want strict ordering of these reads and writes you will have to use some sort of synchronization mechanism. std::atomic<> makes it easier.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <atomic>

void check() {
    struct AB { int a = 0; int b=0; };
    std::atomic<AB> ab;
    {
        std::jthread t2([&](){
            int i = 0;
            AB temp;
            while (true) {
                temp = ab;
                if ( temp.a > temp.b ) break;
                ++i;
            }
            std::cout << "failed at iteration " << i << "\n"
                      // I know at this point a and b may have changed
                      << temp.a << " >= " << temp.b << "\n";
            std::exit(0);
        });
        std::jthread t1([&](){
            while (true) {
                AB temp = ab;
                temp.a++;
                temp.b++;
                ab = temp;
            }
        });
    }
}

int main() {
    check();
}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/Kxeb8d8or

Result:

```
Program returned: 143
Program stderr
Killed - processing time exceeded
```

Comment: even easier -- just use `std::atomic<int>`

Comment: std::atomic<int> Only guarantees that access to that int is atomic, not to both

Comment: It also guarentees sequential consistency between them (memory_order_seq_cst) unless you use explicit opertations with less consistency.  So if you have `a++; b++;` in a thread, no other thread can see the increment of b before the increment of a.  You do need `while (tmp = b, a >= tmp)` in your test loop to ensure that the read of b comes before the read of a, but with that, it should be good.

Comment: There are cases you are not considering. Imagine this: 

(1) Initial a=0 b=0
(2) Thread1 - read "a"  a=0
(3) Thread2 - increment "a" a=1
(4) Thread2 - increment "b" b=1
(5) Thread1 - read "b" b=1
Then you will have a situation where thread1 sees a=0 and b=1, out of order while both are still atomic.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Case at hand: https://godbolt.org/z/vcennM8f6

Comment: That's why you need the read of b before a in thread1 as I stated

Comment: see https://godbolt.org/z/ozhb1saaq

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yes but then you will be introducing so much obscure semantics to the code that you just need an intern change something for hell to break loose and you go nuts to find the bug. Also you are adding not one but TWO locks. This is not better.

Comment: std:atomic<int> is usally lock-free, so this is 0 locks, not 2.  Any use of synchronization is something that interns break all the time if you let them touch your code.

Comment: No, it uses a prefix lock which is very slow. Check the very godbolt you sent me. `lock subl $1, (%rdi)`.  If you make the entire struct atomic you will be guaranteed it never break, it's intern-safe. If you need a team of PhDs to touch your code then you'll never build a startup.